# The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine in c# ASP.NET using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

i am working on a website which uses an API to read data from. The APi returns data in XML format for which i am using Load() of XmlDocument but during the execution I get an Exception "The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine" on this line 
`doc.Load(url);` 
I don't know how to tackle with this problem, I have already searched for answers but couldn't find any good.

Comment: Try to download the XML as a string with e.g. `WebClient`, and see if it gives you more meaningful errors.

Comment: the api i'm am using is an upgraded version of the previous one which i manipulated using the same method but this api isn't working that way

Comment: Add this to your web.config <system.net> <settings> <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" /> </settings> </system.net>

Comment: where in web.config??? in <configuration> or outside it?

Comment: i placed it just before the ending tag of configuration but didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

"Protocol violation" exception is thrown, when client (i.e. XmlDocument class) and server are not able to communicate to each other using given protocol (I assume it is 'http' protocol in your case). This can happen if

- you try to use protocol that server does not understand (for example 'http' vs. 'https')
- server is broken
- something messes up with communication (for example proxy
  server, antivirus software, unstable internet connection, etc.)

You can add following to web.config file - this will create log file "System.Net.trace.log" with detailed log of all communication. You can search it for server's response, or for reason why client refused that response.

```
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true" />
        <sources>
            <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="1024">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="MyTraceFile"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add
              name="MyTraceFile"
              type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData="System.Net.trace.log"
                />
        </sharedListeners>
        <switches>
            <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
        </switches>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Alternatively you can use tools such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to investigate communication.